# How to access the db values to my php page with line breaks(formatted)

Tags: php, html, database

I have a php page where in i am displaying some description elements which is stored in a MYSQL database as

`1.    This ritual is performed to get the blessings of Lord Ganesha (Lord Ganesha removes all obstacles)  2.    This homa is done as per Puranokta/Vedookta procedure3.    This homa mantra for Lord Ganesha is 9 syllables (Navakshara). The core of the homa ceremony involves recitation of ____________`

But when i run my program i need to be displayed as

`1.    This ritual is performed to get the blessings of Lord Shiva

2.    This homa is done as per Puranokta/Vedookta procedure
3.    This homa mantra for Laksmi Devi is 9 syllables (Navakshara). The core of the homa ceremony involves recitation of ____________`

How to do? Can i add line breaks in DB? How to get the formatted DB value?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to make accessing a MYSQL database easier, it is not a database in and of iteslf

Comment: This really depends on how you stored the text in the first place. And it is there that you should look for a fix for this

Comment: Its a one time entry. Directly to the database am entering the values.

Comment: Then add some HTML to it. A simple `<br />` at the end of each line might be enough. That depends upon the HTML that you have around it on the page

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried adding `<br />` still no effect

Comment: Why Don't you insert all the points as a  row instead of storing into a one column and making it a complicated , by storing it as a each row will be very  useful to display and do different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any HTML Code in MySQL but I suggest you yo encode it to Base64 before inserting the value.

```
$html_data = base64_encode($html_data);
```

Now `$html_data` is encoded and then insert it in DB.

Similarly when you fetch the data

```
$html_data = base64_decode($row['html_data']);
```

Now the `$html_data` is decoded and can be directly displayed in php page.